# "Access Token missing or malformed" error while accessing Azure AD Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an account on Azure where we run various applications in docker containers.

I would like to connect to Active Directory on this account and be able to manage various aspects such as creating new users, etc.

I found following API browser:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/graphrbac/users/list

Unfortunately when I log in as a user with admin rights (Global Administrator) and provide tenant ID, when I call users/list endpoint, I get following error with 401 status:

`{
  "odata.error": {
    "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
    "message": {
      "lang": "en",
      "value": "Access Token missing or malformed."
    },
    "date": "2018-07-20T14:01:24",
    "requestId": "9f070c46-a949-41bf-85c9-f1ccf97975db",
    "values": null
  }
}`

What is interesting - if I use any other random endpoint, for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servermanagement/node/list - it works fine. In this case it returns empty set, but at least it doesn't fail with strange authentication error.

Answer (score 2):

I also can **reproduce** the issue that you metioned if I test Users - List Rest API directly from the site.

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/graphrbac/Users/List`

According to exception, the root cause of the issue is token audience. You could check the actual access token in the [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/).

You could get that the audience is `https://management.core.windows.net/`. The token that is acquired will work for other Azure Services like webapps, compute, ResourceManager, etc. **but not for Graph.**

You could test it with [Azue AD graph explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/#), then it will work for you.

The audience should be `https://graph.windows.net`

[image]